# When linking a relative image in the display of a block, it's links the width of the entire page?

Tags: html, css

I have found a post that fixes this problem with no specific position value included, but I would like my image to be positioned relatively. When I add a link onto an image and it is displayed as a block and vertically centered, the width of the page becomes a link. How do I stop this?

```css
#logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img id="logo" src="images/diMatteos2.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: what doest that mean "the link of the page becomes a link"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about `position: relative;` but `display: block;`. The block level elements take up full width. If you don't want to use full width, you can replace it using `display: inline-block;`.

```css
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img id="logo" src="images/diMatteos2.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: For some reason it is not centering using this method either?

Comment: @Cooper Sorry, can you please add `a {display: block; text-align: center;}`.

Comment: Hold on, no it didn't. It's linked the whole width again.

Comment: @Cooper Just give `width: 100px; margin: auto;` and that works magically! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Display block makes you to behave a block element, or that's the same: an entire element in document. You can limit its width, but the best practice is that you make something like this.

```
 <div class="center">
      <a href="">
         <img>
      </a>
 </div>

 .center { display:block; margin: 0 auto; position:Relative; text-align:center; }
```

The image can be inline element and the problem disappears.
See the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hzz4q9db/

Comment: This does not centre my image, however.

Comment: Did you see the fiddle?

Comment: Maybe you have the `display:block` to `<img> ` in your css?